# No Resource Identifier found for attribute 'menu'

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to implement a navigation drawer into my app, but when I try to reference my '@menu/navigationdraweritems' file, I get the error:

```
Error:(26) No resource identifier found for attribute 'menu' in package 'com.t99sdevelopment.centralized'
```

Here's my XML...

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/navigationdraweritems" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Also...

```
My gradle dependency: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: is your file here res/menu/navigationdraweritems.xml ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` to work, you need to add the design dependency in you build.gradle:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```